# Spring boot JPA fetch specific column from crudRepository query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im trying to get the "name" field from my user class within my Employee class so i can avoid making an additional query to get the user name.

For the moment, I've only been able to get the user_id this way

My user class

```
@Entity @Table(name="user", schema = "public") @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @Accessors(chain = true)
public class User implements Serializable{
    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "user_id") Long id;
    private @Column(unique = true) String email;
    private String name;
}
```

My Employee class

```
@Entity @Table(name = "employee",schema = "public") @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @Accessors(chain = true)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "employee_id") Long id;
    @JsonIgnore @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id",insertable = false,updatable = false) private User user;
    private @Column(name="fk_user_id") Long userId;
}
```

i know i can not retrieve the name without selecting it so i tried using a custom query on my crudRepository

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT employee.*, public.user.name FROM public.employee INNER JOIN public.user ON public.user.user_id = employee.fk_user_id ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employee> findEmployees();
}
```

The query returns what i expect but i dont know how to fetch the resulted column "name"on my Employee class

Any help or guidance is welcome, thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should select the `Employee` only and then get the name from the fetched `User`. Also I dont think you need the query to be native:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM public.employee e INNER JOIN FETCH e.user")
    List<Employee> findEmployees();
}
```

Then:

```
for(Employee e: findEmplyees){
    String name = e.getUser.getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if i do it that way i will have to make two queries, one to fetch the Employees and other to fetch their corresponding users. And thats what im trying to avoid

Comment: Its an eage fetch so the user will be joined in the same query. If you select only the employee and then call getUser() on it, then yes, another query would made on db in that case

Comment: i just tried the way you told me and got this error on the Browser
Could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet, The console error trace points this org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input but there are no specific causes.  My query is the following @Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Employee e INNER JOIN FETCH User u")

Comment: My mistake. Corrected it

Comment: Thanks @Maciej it works great that way, but still i'm trying to fetch only the user name instead of the whole User, is that possible?, I have only worked with Spring boot, JPA, Hibernate for a week so im still in the fog haha, thanks again for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

When you want to fetch more data then what is described in your entity class, and you don't want to fetch lazy relationships, you could create a new class, for example one DAO class that will have all the attributes you want to fetch. So in your case probably `EmployeeDAO` class with all the attributes of the employee entity plus `userName`. And then use it as a returned collection:

```
@Query(your query)
List<EmployeeDAO> findEmployees();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but if i do it that way, i would have to make a new Entity with his corresponding table or view and im trying to avoid that